# iOS swift | Coach Marks / Walk Through Instructions misbehaving

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, walkthrough

I am using a third party toolkit to generate a walkthrough for an app but when the frame for the walkthrough changes it only shows the last frame and skips the ones before it.

i have tried to pause the flow of coach mark and even to add additional coach marks but it didnt work either. Below is a snippet of my code, any help would be great since i do not understand this toolkit very much.
And how would i change the coach mark message each time?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 139/255, green: 26/255, blue: 137/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
    checkForVolume()
    self.coachMarksController.dataSource = self

    pointOfInterest.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 30, width: 30, height: 50)
    coachMarksController.restoreAfterChangeDidComplete()
    coachMarksController.prepareForChange()
    pointOfInterest.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: 30, width: 130, height: 50)
    coachMarksController.restoreAfterChangeDidComplete()
    coachMarksController.prepareForChange()
    pointOfInterest.frame = CGRect(x: 330, y: 25, width: 35, height: 40)
    coachMarksController.restoreAfterChangeDidComplete()
    coachMarksController.prepareForChange()        
}
```

and when i use coachMarksController.flow.pause() along with coachMarksController.flow.resume() the screen just freezes with overlay but no coach mark at all

Comment: What is the name of that framework you're using?

Comment: Instructions. https://github.com/ephread/Instructions
i guess you are not familiar with ?

Comment: seriously? it seems no one has come across this toolkit

Comment: You might be better off opening a GitHub issue on the repository of the framework, that way you can know for sure people who will be looking at your issue will be familiar with the framework.

Comment: thanks for the advice. it did'nt work, no one had this particular issue